# Outlook mail items last modification time is not getting latest modified time for POP3 settings

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, pop3

I have created an outlook add in. IN which if I drag and an email from sent box to sub folder I am capturing the last modification time.

If I setup an account directly with office 365 emails then it is capturing the latest last modification time.

But if I setup account using POP3 server then it is not getting proper value.

```
            var application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            Folder sent = application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail) as Folder;


            MAPIFolder currentFolderItems = sent.Folders[folder];
            PluginManager plugManager = PluginManager.Instance;         

            MAPIFolder testFodler = (MAPIFolder)sent.Folders[folder];

            foreach (var items in testFodler.Items.OfType<MailItem>())
            {
                logger.Info("Modified :" + items.LastModificationTime);
                logger.Info("Modified UTC TIME :" + items.LastModificationTime.ToUniversalTime());
                logger.Info("plugManager.LastSyncDateTime : " + plugManager.LastSyncDateTime);
                logger.Info("Sent On  :" + items.SentOn);
                logger.Info("Recived Time : " + items.ReceivedTime);
                logger.Info("Emial : "+ items.SenderEmailAddress);
                logger.Info("Recived By : " + items.ReceivedByName); 

            }
```

In this for direct account setup I am getting proper value but for POP3 setup I am getting LastModificationTime as sent time .

I need this time to update db values for  only latest modified items rather than updating all the items .

Comment: So what is the problem? That the last modified time does not get updated when the message is moved? Or that it gets updated?

Comment: It does not get updated  with POP3 settings.

Comment: Whether the store provider (PST?) decides to update the last modified time when a message is moved is up to that particular provider - after all, it wasn't really modified. More than that, PST provider does not even change the message entry id.

Comment: Yes it is updating if we create setup through direct email . Does it different if we create through manual setup using POP or IMAP.